# How to make input invisible but not hidden?

Tags: html, css

I'm currently trying to create a fully working sudoku web page and I'm having a little trouble styling. I'm kind of a noob to the whole HTML CSS game. Here is a code snippet of what I currently have.

```css
.soduku {
  display: block;
  justify-content: center;
}

.sudoku__board {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  height: 500px;
  width: 40%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.sudoku__row,
.sudoku__space {
  border: 2px dotted gray;
}

.sudoku__row:nth-child(3n) {
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}

.sudoku__space:nth-child(3n+1) {
  border-left: 2px solid black;
}

tr: nth-child(3n+0) {
  border-left: 3px solid black;
}
```

```html
<section class="sudoku">
  <table class='sudoku__board'>
    <tr class="sudoku__row">
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="sudoku__row">
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="sudoku__row">
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="sudoku__row">
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="sudoku__row">
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="sudoku__row">
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="sudoku__row">
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="sudoku__row">
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="sudoku__row">
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
    </tr>
  </table>
</section>
```

Basically this creates almost exactly what I'm looking for except the inputs are too wide and chunky and very visible. I'm essentially trying to find an option that would be equivalent to if type were hidden except the user can still write within the box and have the number visible. Any ideas or references to helpful pages is appreciated.

Comment: Your question is very confusing, can you explain further?

Comment: Style the inputs themselves: `input { appearance: none; -webkit-appearance: none; border: none; width: 20px; height: 20px;` or something?

Answer (score 1):

You are tantalisingly close to solving it, all you need to do is style your inputs themselves so they get rid of their default styling:

```
input {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  border: none;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```js
document.querySelectorAll( '.sudoku__space input' ).forEach(input => {
    
  input.type = 'number';
  input.min = 1;
  input.max = 9;
  input.step = 1;
  
})
```

```css
.soduku {
  display: block;
  justify-content: center;
}

.sudoku__board {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.sudoku__row,
.sudoku__space {
  border: 2px dotted gray;
}

.sudoku__row:nth-child(3n) {
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}

.sudoku__space:nth-child(3n+1) {
  border-left: 2px solid black;
}

tr: nth-child(3n+0) {
  border-left: 3px solid black;
}

input {
  appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  border: none;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<section class="sudoku">
  <table class='sudoku__board'>
    <tr class="sudoku__row">
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="sudoku__row">
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="sudoku__row">
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="sudoku__row">
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="sudoku__row">
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="sudoku__row">
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="sudoku__row">
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="sudoku__row">
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="sudoku__row">
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
      <th class="sudoku__space"><input type="text" maxlength="1"></th>
    </tr>
  </table>
</section>
```

As a little extra I have added a script that will amend all your inputs (because I'm lazy its a script) so they will actually look like this:

```
<input type="number" min="1" max="9" step="1" maxlength="1" />
```

Which will limit all the values in those boxes to `1` through `9`.

Comment: @DavidJawHpan When you focus on the element? That's not a _border_, that's an _outline_. Best leave that in for accessibility. All the other borders come from the table, not the input.

Comment: This added with color makes the perfect look thank you! Out of curiosity do you know why text-align: center; wouldn't work that and the text size are the only things that doesn't look quite right.

Comment: Well, I presume its because the `number` type of the input adds its own controls to the right, otherwise text align should work just fine. Text size can just be adjusted by setting `font-size`.